# Remove leading zeros only in IP addresses

Tags: regex, perl, ip

I need to remoe all leading zeros in a csv from all IP addresses, but not others (like hostnames).

I got the following, which does remove all

```
s/(?<!\d)0+(?=\d)//g
```

sample CSV:

```
192.168.001.000,any comment,host0003.zone.com
010.001.100.000,any long 000 string,host004.zone.com
```

should become

```
192.168.1.0,any comment,host0003.zone.com
10.1.100.0,any long 000 string,host004.zone.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: I attached a before and after CSV example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Regexp::Common` and `Net::IP` if you don't mind using CPAN modules.

```
$ <sample.csv perl -MRegexp::Common -MNet::IP -ple 's/($RE{net}{IPv4})/Net::IP->new($1)->ip/ge'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/(?:^|\.)0+(?=\d)//g;
    print $line;
}


__DATA__
192.168.001.000,any comment,host0003.zone.com
010.001.100.000,any long 000 string,host004.zone.com
```

prints:

```
192.168.1.0,any comment,host0003.zone.com
10.1.100.0,any long 000 string,host004.zone.com
```

In any case, I strongly recommend that you use a CPAN module to parse the CSV file, like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).

Comment: okay, got it. but I was looking for more general approach that does not rely on the IP to be in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

for (<DATA>) {
   print join(",",map{ if($_=~/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/s){$_=~s/^0*(\d+)/$1/sg;$_=~s/^0*?\./0/sg;$_=~s/\.0+(\d+)/\.$1/sg;$_;}else{$_} } split /,/is,$_);
}

__DATA__
192.168.001.000,any comment,host0003.zone.com
010.001.100.000,any long 000 string,host004.zone.com
```

Answer (score -1):

The unix regex below may help:

```
',\{0,2\}\([0][0-9]\{2\}\.\)\([0-9]\{3\}\.\)\{2\}'.
```