# Remove leading zeros in IP address using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ip-address, leading-zero

Remove unnecessary zeros in IP address:

```
100.020.003.400  ->  100.20.3.400
001.200.000.004  ->  1.200.0.4
000.002.300.000  ->  0.2.300.0   (optional silly test)
```

My attempt does not work well in all cases:

```
import re
ip = re.sub('[.]0+', '.', ip_with_zeroes)
```

There are similar question but for other languages:

- [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24949991)
- [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044684)

Please provide solutions for both Python v2 and v3.

Comment: clean_ip = ".".join([str(int(x)) for x in ip.split(".")])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [netaddr library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr/) and then it has the `ZEROFILL` flag:

```
import netaddr

ip = "055.023.156.008"

no_zero_ip = netaddr.IPAddress(ip, flags=netaddr.ZEROFILL).ipv4()

# IPAddress('55.23.156.8')
```

You probably want to change the `no_zero_ip` result to a string or something else if you don't want the `IPAddress` type

Answer (score 5):

```
ip = "100.020.003.400"
print '.'.join(str(int(part)) for part in ip.split('.'))
# 100.20.3.400
```

Comment: just a note, the square braces are superfluous

Comment: @Alter Not nesscarily. [`''.join()` constructs a list from the iterable passed in](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/join.h#L22) anyway, so it would probably improve the speed to pass in a list before hand.

Comment: interesting! I'm trying to test it now. I looked into `PySequence_Fast` and can't find anything that explicitly says it does lists faster, but that may be true.

Comment: with 10** 6 auto-generated ip addresses, the list method takes ~11.2 seconds and the generator takes ~11.5 seconds averaged over multiple runs. So it is slightly faster. *edit* I was including the time to generate ips, without that, it's more pronounced at 3.2s to 2.8s

Answer (score 3):

For prior to 2.6 you can use the string-modulo operator. But let's not talk about that.

This should do it as far back as the [`format` method](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) was introduced (2.6):

```
'.'.join('{0}'.format(int(i)) for i in ip.split('.'))
```

Optionally eliminate the index the for python ≥3.3 or ≥2.7 (I think):

```
'.'.join('{}'.format(int(i)) for i in ip.split('.'))
```

And for python ≥3.6 only, we get to f-string it up:

```
'.'.join(f'{int(i)}' for i in ip.split('.'))
```

If you can use the last, I highly recommend it. It's quite satisfying.

Comment: Nice! This works for me on Python 3.6 and Python 3.5. Not sure about Python 2 though.

Comment: @ChristianDean Should work in 2.7 at least. Not sure about others.

Comment: OK Phantom downvoter. Any chance you want to explain yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture group to match the last digit and copy it, to prevent all the digits from being replaced.

```
ip = re.sub(r'\b0+(\d)', r'\1', ip_with_zeroes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by "." convert to integer and then string, and join by "."

```
ip = ".".join([str(int(i)) for i in ip.split(".")])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to do this on Python 3.3+ is to use built-in `ipaddress` module

```
import ipaddress
print(str(ipaddress.ip_address("127.000.000.1")))
```

will print

```
127.0.0.1
```

But note that, you'll get an `ValueError` exception on invalid IP addresses. The good part is this also works with IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Thank you for proposing `ipaddress` as [Reut Sharabani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853401/938111) did in 2017 but `ipaddress` fails to remove leading zeros from `"010.10.10.10"`. The raised `ValueError: u'010.10.10.10' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address` is surprising because `"10.10.10.10"` is a valid IPv4 address. Therefore module `ipaddress` is not a good option :-( For your information `ipaddress` can also be used by Python 2.7 but input string should be `u"10.10.10.10"`. Cheers