# Built in libs to give untrimmed ipv6 address?

Tags: python-3.x, ipv6, inet, leading-zero

How do I trim leading zeroes in an ipv6 address string in python?

For eg: I need 1:1:1:1:1:1:0:1 to be trimmed to 1:1:1:1:1:1::1

I have tried using socket.inet_ntop and socket.inet_pton but they do not help in my case

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import struct
address = '1:1:1:1:1:1:0:1'
addr = socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6,socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, address))
print (addr)
```

This prints the same string as the output 1:1:1:1:1:1:0:1

I have also tried the ipaddress lib which produces the same output as above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ipaddress
ip = '1:1:1:1:1:1:0:1'
print(str(ipaddress.ip_address(ip)))
```

I tried using the netaddr lib by referring to the top voted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852721/remove-leading-zeros-in-ip-address-using-python) question but get an import error. I'm using Python 3.0.

I have also tried using [this](https://pypi.org/project/IPy/) library but get an ImportError: No module named 'IPy' error

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from IPy import IP
print(IP('1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A'))
```

I'm surprised to find that no one has had a real clear cut solution in a built in library to solve this problem. Can someone help?

Comment: You are not supposed to compress a single `0`. _[RFC 5952, Section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-4)_, explains the proper IPv6 address formatting, including: "_The symbol "::" MUST NOT be used to shorten just one 16-bit 0 field. For example, the representation 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1 is correct, but 2001:db8::1:1:1:1:1 is not correct._"

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for your clarification.
socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6,socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, "1:1:1:1:1:1::1") returns 1:1:1:1:1:1:0:1. This very much solves my use case.